# How to convert Shapefile geometries to WKB using OGR?

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr, well-known-binary

I got the geometry of a feature of the shapefile, and i want to save that geometry in the postgis (in WKB formats like it happens when we import shapefiles using shp2pgsql and psql commands). How do I convert then

To get Geometry i have used OSGeo OGR library
eg:

```
feat = layer.GetFeature(0)
geometry = feat.GetGeometryRef()
```

and I have got

```
<osgeo.ogr.Geometry; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRGeometryShadow *' at 0x0096A2D8> >
```

so how will convert it into the WKB geometry?
I am using Python for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to call the `ExportToWkb` function.

```
import ogr
# Get the driver
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
# Open a shapefile
shapefileName = "D:/temp/myshapefile.shp"
dataset = driver.Open(shapefileName, 0)

layer = dataset.GetLayer()
for index in xrange(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(index)
    wkb = feature.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkb()
```

Comment: Thanks geographika .. is there any resource available whare i can look for the different api's available.

Comment: The Python bindings mirror the OGR C API http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRGeometry.html